# Use Fixed Private IP Range for Fargate within Subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate

I want to utilize AWS ECS fargate but I have a requirement from the security team to restrict the Private IP range of my fargate instances within a subnet.

From the [AWS networking docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-networking.html), It seems like it is possible to use a seperate non-managed ENI to specify the private IP address. Is there a method to use a static IP range for the fargate instances?

> For tasks that use the Fargate launch type, the task ENI that is
> created is fully managed by AWS Fargate. Depending on which Fargate
> platform version your task uses, the network traffic for your task may
> also use a separate Fargate-owned ENI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fixed private IP range is decided based on the subnet(s) that you will deploy your Fargate tasks into.

If you create seperate subnet(s) for your Fargate tasks, and then ensure that only Fargate tasks are launched in these subnets you could then provide this range to your security team.

Fargate creates the ENI when it launches the task, with a random private IP address form the pool of available IPs in your subnet(s) range.

Comment: Now, I am given a subnet, but told to use a fixed IP range. Does that means its not possible?

Comment: A subnet defines the CIDR range of the subnet when it is configured. :)

Comment: I mean, a fixed IP range within the subnet's CIDR range ...

Comment: If you're sharing the subnet with other resources it is hard to define a range as other resources may also exist in that range that are not Fargate containers. It would be simpler to create new ranges just for Fargate. You can use a minimum range of `/28` if you want to keep the subnet small :)